Creating an Infinite Scroll Carousel with Clickable Indicators
I’m trying to create a div with horizontal scrolling, similar to a carousel, containing multiple cards that can scroll from left to right. The scroll should be infinite, meaning that once the last card is reached, the scrolling should restart from the first card.
I’ve managed to achieve this, but I’m having an issue with the indicators that should appear below the div. I want to have dots corresponding to the various cards, and when clicked, they should allow navigation between the cards, resetting the scroll of the div.
To make the scroll infinite, I’ve duplicated the cards when reaching the end, and this part works fine. The problem arises when I try to manually calculate the scroll with the cloned elements, as the dots remain in the original number (excluding the cloned ones). How can I solve this? Do you have any examples? I can’t seem to find anything online.


You could always use something like Glide.js to accomplish this design goal.
If you want help updating the state representing number of carousel items, we will need to see some of your code to reproduce the issue and be able to see why your state isn't updating.
Here's an example of implementing a carousel using Glide.js to handle all the looping logic for you.


new Glide('.glide', {
    type: 'carousel',
    perView: 3,
    animationDuration: 500,
    loop: true
}).mount();
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.glide__slide {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 200px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background: lightgrey;
}
.glide__arrows button {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  background: lightgrey;
}
.glide__bullets {
  padding: 10px;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.core.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.theme.min.css">
<div class="glide">
    <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
        <ul class="glide__slides">
            <li class="glide__slide a">1</li>
            <li class="glide__slide b">2</li>
            <li class="glide__slide c">3</li>
            <li class="glide__slide d">4</li>
            <li class="glide__slide e">5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Navigation Arrows -->
    <div class="glide__arrows" data-glide-el="controls">
        <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--left" data-glide-dir="<">Prev</button>
        <button class="glide__arrow glide__arrow--right" data-glide-dir=">">Next</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Dots Navigation -->
    <div class="glide__bullets" data-glide-el="controls[nav]">
        <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=0"></button>
        <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=1"></button>
        <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=2"></button>
        <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=3"></button>
        <button class="glide__bullet" data-glide-dir="=4"></button>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.min.js"></script>



